# How to put multiple condition in EL expression?

Tags: jsf, el

I  need to check two condition in my EL expression.
I put those condition in this way:

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{iw:length(beanObject.methodName) gt 1} and #{iw:length(beanObject.methodName) le 25} ">
</h:panelGroup>
```

But it doesnt work.
Though if I put single condition like this:

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{iw:length(beanObject.methodName) gt 1}">
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Can anyone tell that why multiple conditions are not working?

Comment: Change rendered="#{iw:length(beanObject.methodName) gt 1} and #{iw:length(beanObject.methodName) le 25} "  to  rendered="#{(iw:length(beanObject.methodName) gt 1) and (iw:length(beanObject.methodName) le 25)} "

Comment: Upvote the comment